# REST api to get the value of richhtml field without tags

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, rest

I'm trying to get a field named `Content` from list which is of type `RichHtml`. When I try to get this using `REST api` call, I'm getting the content the html tags. How can I get the value only from this field using a rest api call ?

Comment: "The value" has HTML tags in it, that what makes it a RichHTML field (the possiblity to use tags)

Comment: How can I get the data only from that field? without tags ?

Comment: I think you can't, you will have to parse the value you get and strip out any tags with for example some javascript method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function allows to extract text content from Html.

Example:

```
var query = "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/getItemById(1)";
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + query,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function(data){
      var pageContentText = $(data.d.PublishingPageContent).text();
      console.log(pageContentText);
    },
    error:  function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```